# Like Button Generator not working

Tags: facebook-like, code-generation

I am trying to add a “Like Button” to a friend’s website (first time trying this).  When I first used the code generator a couple of days ago, the generator showed a rendition of the button to the right of the fields.
Now there is no rendition and once I “Get Code” the XFBML, IFRAME and URL links do not work.  It also appears that the code generated is not what I requested via the user input fields. (i.e. when selecting Color Scheme Dark I find the following in the code generated  data-colorscheme="light" )
Regards
Derek

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug in the developers tool right now.  It has been reported to Facebook using their bug reporting tool, and they have confirmed that it's an issue.  You can subscribe to the bug report here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/321035314684250 .  Use the little "Subscribe" button in the upper right corner.